# Prove $A^{2}=0$ iff $C\left(A\right)=R^{0}\left(A\right) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm learning some Linear Algebra through a University Textbook and I've come across this question which I have a hard time solving:

Let There be a square Matrix A. 
Prove that $A^{2}=0$ iff $C\left(A\right)=R^{0}\left(A\right) $

where $R^{0}\left(A\right)$ is the nullspace (kernel).

I just don't understand how to approach this question. I know how to find the four fundamental subspaces given a certain array, but not too much apart from that.

**EDIT: Apparently the term C(A) is not standard, in the textbook it refers to the subspace of the columns of A

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: What's $C(A){}$?

Comment: Oops, thought it was some kind of standard notation. The textbook refers to it as the subspace of columns of the matrix A

Comment: Then the result is wrong, consider the case when $A$ is the zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Saying $A^2=0$ means that every column of $A$ is in the kernel $R^\circ(A)$, since the columns of $A^2$ are obtained by applying $A$ to the columns of$~A$. In other words it is equivalent to $C(A)\subseteq R^\circ(A)$.

But you cannot conclude from $A^2=0$ that $C(A)=R^\circ(A)$. The rank nullity theorem says that always $\dim(C(A))+\dim(R^\circ(A))=n$ (the size of the square matrix$~A$), and this can even prevent the two subspaces from ever being equal, if $n$ is odd. In any case, one can always (if $n>0$) choose $A$ such that $C(A)\subsetneq R^\circ(A)$; for instance $A=0$, or when $n>2$ any matrix with just one nonzero entry, not situated on the main diagonal.

Answer (score -1):

It might not be as formal as a mathematician would put it, but this is how I would put it:

1. $Ker(A) =$ $\{x \in R^n: Ax=0\}$
2. $C(A) =$ $\langle a_i \rangle,$ where $A=[a_1 a_2 ... a_n]$  and thus, $C(A) =$ $\sum_i\alpha_ia_i$ for $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

If:

$Ker(A) = C(A)$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\{x = \sum_i\alpha_ia_i \in R^n: Ax=0\}$

$\leftrightarrow$ $\{A (\sum_i\alpha_ia_i)=0\}$

$\leftrightarrow$ $\{A (A\alpha^T)=0\}$

$\leftrightarrow$ $\{A^2\alpha^T=0\}$

$\leftrightarrow$ $A^2=0$, assuming that $\alpha^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of arbitrary constants.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Your first line is wrong. $\mathrm{ker}(A) = C(A)$ only *implies* that $A(\sum \alpha_i a_i) = 0$ for all $\alpha_i$. To get the reverse implication, you need to prove that these are the *only* $x$ such that $Ax = 0$.